# How to disable the notifications on Edge and Safari browser using selenium java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, microsoft-edge, safaridriver

How to disable the notifications on Edge and Safari browser using Selenium and Java?

I have used the following code to disable the notification on the browsers.

```
caps.setCapability("disable-infobars", true);
caps.setCapability("--disable-notifications", true);
```

But it is not working as expected. Do I miss anything here?

Comment: Did you get any solution to block push notifications on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way to close Push notifications on safari.
Try navigating to the URL twice, this seems to automatically adding the URL to Notifications DENY list.

driver.navigate().to("");
driver.navigate().to("");

Rajesh